# Efficiency of repeatedly adding to a RealmList

Tags: android, realm

In one of the Realm code examples they have the following,

```
for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    Cat cat = realm.createObject(Cat.class);
    cat.setName("Cat_" + j);
    person.getCats().add(cat);
}
```

What happens if `i` happens to be very large, as in over 1k or higher? It would mean that `person.getCats()` is grabbing a long list only to add one value. Is this efficient? If not, what would a better approach be?

Comment: `getCats()` will only grab a reference to the list so even a long list shouldn't be a problem. One of Realm's principles is zero-copy, so once backed by Realm, they are not copied.

Comment: This is actually the kind of answer I was looking for...If you post it as an answer with any other technical details you know, I'll get it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getCats()` will only grab a reference to the list so even a long list shouldn't be a problem.

One of Realm's principles is zero-copy, so once backed by Realm, they are not copied - see http://www.slideshare.net/ChristianMelchior/realm-building-a-mobile-database.

Answer (score 1):

You're right. This is not the best approch, you will get the list on every row:

1. use transaction has you have batches of work to do. All will be
   exectued at once (all together)
2. loop  to add,
3. commit transaction every  COMMITSIZE

   ```
   long added=0;
   long  COMMITSIZE =100;

   //open transaction
   realm.beginTransaction();
   pCats = person.getCats();

   for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
       Cat cat = realm.createObject(Cat.class);
       cat.setName("Cat_" + j);
       pCats.add(cat);


       if(added%COMMITSIZE == 0){
           realm.commitTransaction();
           //reopen transaction
           realm.beginTransaction();
       }


   }

   //commit transaction
   realm.commitTransaction();
   ```

Comment: what about using your approach but maybe doing a realm.commitTransaction() every 100 entries or so that way if the process is interrupted, the entire data set isn't lost?

Comment: I also just realized this mean creating thousands of cat objects too...Sticking  with SQLite may be a better solution for what I'm thinking.